# Control Matlab GUI by Android device

Tags: android, matlab, user-interface, controls, remote-access

Is it possible to control a matlab gui via an android device (like a tablet) .. I am measuring something and I need to show/display a set of data remotely.

Also controlling it remotely will be very usefull?

Comment: Yes it is. Next question please.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. Set up a web server that MATLAB can read/write to and your android can do the same.

Hint #1 - This will take more than two lines of code

Hint #2 - You will need to use something other than MATLAB for the server most likely (although it is technically possible to use MATLAB as a server I am pretty sure)

Hint #3 The reason your question has so many downvotes is because it is very vague. Make sure that next time you ask SPECIFIC questions :)

Hint #4 MATLAB mobile is most likely NOT what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [MATLAB Mobile](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/mobile/)? Not sure if it works with GUIs, but you can definitely control MATLAB remotely and access basic functionality.

**EDIT**: it definitely won't work with GUIs. Here's what the FAQ says about it:

MATLAB Mobile does not support:

- Tools that use graphical user interfaces, such as the Curve Fitting app and the Simulink graphical environment
- An editor for creating or editing files Interactive figures (Although you can zoom, pan, and add data tips, the figures do not support rotating and other figure callbacks.)
- Retrieval of more than ten graphics from the desktop in a single command
- The `doc` command (To view function documentation, use the help command. Alternatively, open the web browser on your device and navigate to the product documentation at
  mathworks.com/help/matlabmobile/.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You can just use a bluetooth-serial equipment which is very cheap, you can buy that on ebay. With this, you can send you command from Android device to your computer by bluetooth. Then the bluetooth-serial equipment can transfer the blurtooth signal in to serial. Then just use your matlab to read the serial data and recognise the command. Sorry, my english is not so good... hope this can help you~

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to install an Xserver (freely available from the store) on the Android device in question and start Matlab with the DISPLAY environment variable set accordingly, e.g.

```
env DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0 matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r yourscript.m
```

This works from GNU/Linux systems, I don't know if Windows-ports of X work. We're currently testing this for use in an experiment.